# How to configure color when convert CV2 numpy array to QImage?

Tags: python, qt, opencv, numpy, pyqt

The program is based on pyqt and opencv. I plan to read and process image with opencv while using QT as GUI.

when I open a gray image, The result is OK. But it will change the color of image when opening a color image. I guess it's because I made mistake when I convert numpy array to OImage type, but I can't figure out how to correct it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys

import cv2
from cv2 import cv

QTextCodec.setCodecForTr(QTextCodec.codecForName("utf8"))

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Show Image with pyqt")

        self.imageLabel=QLabel()
        self.imageLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored,QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.imageLabel)

        self.image=QImage()

        self.createActions()
        self.createMenus()

        self.cv_img = None

    def createActions(self):
        self.fileOpenAction=QAction(QIcon(":/fileopen.png"),self.tr("Open"),self)
        self.fileOpenAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        self.fileOpenAction.setStatusTip(self.tr("Open the file"))
        self.connect(self.fileOpenAction,SIGNAL("triggered()"),self.slotOpenFile)

        self.exitAction=QAction(QIcon(":/filequit.png"),self.tr("Quit"),self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        self.setStatusTip(self.tr("Quit"))
        self.connect(self.exitAction,SIGNAL("triggered()"),self.close)

    def createMenus(self):
        fileMenu=self.menuBar().addMenu(self.tr("File"))
        fileMenu.addAction(self.fileOpenAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)


    def slotOpenFile(self):
        fileName=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,self.tr("Open a file"),\
            ".",self.tr("Image File(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)"))

        cvfilename=fileName.toLocal8Bit().data()

        if fileName.isEmpty()==False:

            cvfilename=fileName.toLocal8Bit().data() #convert Qstring to char*
            self.cv_img = cv2.imread(cvfilename) #read image with opencv
            cv2.imshow("Show Image with Opencv",self.cv_img) #show image with opencv, this is the right result

            self.image =QImage(self.cv_img.tostring(),\
                self.cv_img.shape[0],self.cv_img.shape[1],QImage.Format_RGB888) #convert numpy array to QImage
            self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
            self.resize(self.image.width(),self.image.height())

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
main=MainWindow()
main.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: Here is the result with color image, the image color changes when show it by using QT, but OK with simple opencv]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert the image data from BGR to RGB. You also need to swap width and height (see below) -- your code only works for images with same width and height.

```
self.cv_img = cv2.imread(cvfilename)

if self.cv_img != None:
    # Notice the dimensions.
    height, width, bytesPerComponent = cv_img.shape
    bytesPerLine = bytesPerComponent * width;

    cv2.imshow("Show Image with Opencv", self.cv_img)

    # Convert to RGB for QImage.
    cv2.cvtColor(self.cv_img, cv.CV_BGR2RGB, self.cv_img)

    self.image = QImage(self.cv_img.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

Comment: After the modify as you suggest, the code can show PNG and BMP image well, but have a kind of shift for JPG image. Do you have any idea why? Thank you.

Comment: OK, fixed. You need the bytesPerLine value (I think it'll be always 3).

Comment: Sorry, but with "self.image = QImage(self.cv_img.data, width, height, 3, QImage.Format_RGB888)" It will not show image anymore:(

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be basically "bytesPerLine = 3 * width" (fixed).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is pretty old thread, but for me cv2.cvtColor works really slow.
I found another function that may help those who will need in the future (took me forever to find this remedy):

```
def cv2_to_qimage(cv_img):

    height, width, bytesPerComponent = cv_img.shape
    bgra = np.zeros([height, width, 4], dtype=np.uint8)
    bgra[:, :, 0:3] = cv_img
    return QtGui.QImage(bgra.data, width, height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
```

Hope you'll find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Below code has **color-filter** update for openCV3.x versions. Code example comes from [hluk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454171/hluk).

```
import cv2
from cv2 import CV

...<snippet>...

self.cv_img = cv2.imread(cvfilename)

if self.cv_img != None:
    # Notice the dimensions.
    height, width, bytesPerComponent = cv_img.shape
    bytesPerLine = bytesPerComponent * width;

    cv2.imshow("Show Image with Opencv", self.cv_img)

    # Convert to RGB for QImage.
    cv2.cvtColor(self.cv_img, cv2.COlOR_BGR2RGB, self.cv_img)

    self.image = QImage(self.cv_img.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
```