# How to display image in Qt Label?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, pyqt4

i am facing some problem in displaying image on a form in Qt label...'b' is the image that i am passing to a constructor ,the image is getting displayed when i am showing it in a constructor but when i am setting it in label,i am still getting a form without image .neither it is showing any error.

```
def on_clicked_micro(self):
        self.obj3=MyForm2(b=self.blur)
        self.obj3.show()
        self.hide()

class MyForm2(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_image3):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,b=None):
            QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
            self.imgPreProc=imagePreProcessor()
            cv2.imshow('blur',b) #############displaying the image #############
            self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(b))
```

Answer (score 2):

Type of variable `b` is return from `cv2.imread('picture.bmp')`. And class `QtGui.QPixmap` is pass image by file name (or path) not cv object. It should be not show it.

It have possibly to fix them 2 way;

1) Your convert them in `QtGui.QImage` by using set array data, width and height (Example for convert it, your can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676888/how-to-configure-color-when-convert-numpy-array-to-qimage) answer or [this](http://wrdeoftheday.com/?page_id=2) blog). And convert to `QtGui.QPixmap` by using [QPixmap QPixmap.fromImage (QImage image, Qt.ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt.AutoColor)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpixmap.html#fromImage). And use same method to load it in `QtGui.QLabel`. And don't forget set layout and size of `QtGui.QLabel`. If image your pass in `QtGui.QLabel` is very small. I will can't see them.

```
class MyForm2(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_image3):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,b=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.imgPreProc=imagePreProcessor()
        cv2.imshow('blur',b)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        myQImage = self.imageOpenCv2ToQImage(b)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(myQImage))

   def imageOpenCv2ToQImage (self, cv_img):
        height, width, bytesPerComponent = cv_img.shape
        bytesPerLine = bytesPerComponent * width;
        cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.CV_BGR2RGB, cv_img)
        return QtGui.QImage(cv_img.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

2) Your add variable `path image file name` to pass image to `QtGui.QPixmap` directly in constructor. It easy than solve No.1. And don't forget set layout and size of `QtGui.QLabel` too.

```
class MyForm2(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_image3):
    def __init__(self, pathFileName, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.imgPreProc = imagePreProcessor()
        cv2.imshow('blur', cv2.imread(pathFileName))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(pathFileName))
```